# Increment frequency of attempts based on IP and login details combination

Tags: perl, loops, logging, increment

I have the following log file

```
2016-04-29 15:56:48+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:46055 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: 3b8d22b5]
2016-04-29 15:56:49+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,28,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 16:11:14+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 52.28.89.99:53059 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: a6c0fac1]
2016-04-29 16:17:42+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 13.92.114.157:1032 (172.17.0.2:2222) [session: d33e1566]
2016-04-29 19:07:10+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:45178 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: fafec37d]
2016-04-29 19:07:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,0,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 19:42:58+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:56925 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: 539960a3]
2016-04-29 19:42:58+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,1,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 20:39:03+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 89.248.167.131:54138 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: b9f550df]
2016-04-29 20:39:03+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,2,89.248.167.131] login attempt [root/root] succeeded
2016-04-29 21:13:41+0000 [cowrie.ssh.transport.HoneyPotSSHFactory] New connection: 141.8.83.213:64400 (172.17.0.6:2222) [session: e696835c]
2016-04-29 21:13:59+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test123] failed
2016-04-29 21:14:10+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test1234] failed
2016-04-29 21:14:13+0000 [SSHService ssh-userauth on HoneyPotTransport,3,141.8.83.213] login attempt [user1/test123] failed
```

I want to increment a value called frequency whenever the IP is found and the same username and password are used to login. For that I want to output the SourcePort, the status[failed/succedded] and the total number of occurrences of the IP, and user/pass combination.

So for instance, taking the last three entries, the result would be

```
Port,Status,Occurrences
64400,failed,2
64400,failed,1
```

This is the code[perl] I have so far: [Thankyou in advance]

```
 $ip = "";
        $port = "";
        $usr = "";
        $pass = "";
        $status = "";
        $frequency = 0;

        #Given this is a user/pass attempt honeypot logger, I will use a wide character to reduce the possibility of stopping
        #the WEKA CSV loader from functioning by using smileyface as seperators.


        while(my $lines = <LOG2>){

                if($lines =~ /New connection/){

                ($ip, $port) = (split /[\[\]\s:()]+/, $lines)[7,8];

                }
                if($lines =~ /login attempt/){#and the ip of the new connection

                if($lines =~ /$ip/){
                ($usr, $pass, $status) = (split /[\s:\[\]\/]+/, $lines)[-3,-2,-1];

                        if($lines =~/$ip/ && $lines =~/$usr/ && $lines =~ /$pass/){

                        $frequency++

                        }

                        if($ip && $port && $usr && $pass && $status ne ""){
                                print FILE2 join "$seperator",($port, $status, $frequency, $end);
                                print FILE2 "\n";
                        }
                        }


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a hash to record all the information for the given IP, username, and password. I used another hash (%port_by_ip) to track what port occurred last with an IP, it means that if there are several connections from the same IP before a login, the last one is used to extract the port.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my (%port_by_ip, %login);

while (<>) {
    if (my ($ip, $port) = /New connection: ([0-9.]+):([0-9]+)/
    ) {
        $port_by_ip{$ip} = $port;
    } elsif (my ($ip, $user, $password, $status)
             = m{,([0-9.]+)\] login attempt \[(.*)/(.*)\] (.*)}
         ) {
        $login{$ip}{$user}{$password}{count}++;
        $login{$ip}{$user}{$password}{$status}++;
        $login{$ip}{$user}{$password}{port}{ $port_by_ip{$ip} }++;
    }
}

print Dumper \%login;
```

Comment: After inserting my log in <>, it works and outputs the following on screen :

[output](http://dumptext.com/ABO7DQPM).

Is there a way to represent the data as asked in op, under "the result would be"? It is counting the combinations and instances which is good but I need an output as shown to be able to use it as a training file for WEKA

Comment: Read [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut) (Mark's very short tutorial about references) on how to access nested structures in Perl.

Comment: `printToFile ($file, \%login);
undef %login;

sub printToFile{


        my ($file, $login_ref) = %_;
        open FILE, $file or die "Can't write '$file': $!";
        local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
        local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
        print FILE Dumper $login_ref;
        close(FILE) or die "Can't close '$file': $!";
}
`

Comment: Following the sub out method of the following perlmonks [post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=704380)

Getting error use of uninitialised value $file at open

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
                        $frequency++
```

write

```
                        $frequency{join ':', $port, $ip, $usr, $pass}{$status}++
```

- this counts the occurrences of the various combinations. Furthermore remove the `print`s from the inner loop - we can print the total numbers only after the loop, e. g:

```
while (($key, $value) = each %frequency)
{
    ($port) = split /:/, $key;
    while (($status, $occurrences) = each %{$value})
    {
        print FILE2 "$port,$status,$occurrences\n";
    }
}
```